# Выполнить процедуру и наполнить модель

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

В общем, у меня есть процедура, которая возвращает табличные данные и есть EF Context.

Я могу как-то сделать `exec` этой процедуры с параметрами и попросить EF замапить их на модель, которой нету в контексте?

Или я обязательно должен добавить модель в контекст, а потом извлеч exec?

Или как-то вообще можно сделать красивее?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете выгружать нужные данные в созданную модель и не обязательно, что бы она была добавлена в контексте. 
Примере: (асинхронный вызов можете заменить на синхронный)

```
public class Model
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Data { get; set; }
}

var result = await context.Entity.FromSqlRaw(“select Id, Data from Entity”).ToListAsync();
```

Либо

```
var result = context.Entity
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.MyEntityProcedure")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ну я же получается, что должен объявить Model, как свойство контекста?

Comment: Нет, вам не обязательно объявлять как свойство контекста. Это может быть DTO класс. И вы заполняете его данными из DB.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел решение:

1. Регистрируем нашу модель в контексте, как  `builder.HasNoKey();`, но поле в самом контексте не создаем.
2. Там где хотим наполнить нашу модель юзаем:

   ```
   var result = context.Set<ProcTable>().
   FromSqlInterpolated($"exec dbo.Proc {Param1},{Param2}");
   ```